# Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve given by the equation at the given point

Tags: derivatives

$$ \tan {xy^2}=\frac{2xy}{\pi}$$

at the point $(-π,1/2)$

How do I find the derivative of this equation?

Comment: Have you done implicit differentiation yet?

Comment: Yes I have, not very experience though.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\tan \theta$? if you don't know, google it. From that, can you use the chain rule to differentiate $\tan {xy^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

We use implicit differentiation for this one:
$$
\sec^2(xy^2)(y^2+2xyy') = \frac{2y}{\pi}+\frac{2xy'}{\pi} 
$$

At the point $x=-\pi$, $y=1/2$, we can plug these in the equation and solve for $y'$:
$$
\sec^2(-\pi/4)(\frac{1}{4}-y'\pi{})=\frac{1}{\pi}-2y'\iff \frac{1}{2}-\pi\frac{y'}{2}=\frac{1}{\pi}-2y' \iff y'(\frac{4-\pi}{2})=\frac{2-\pi}{2\pi} \iff \\
y'=\frac{2-\pi}{\pi(4-\pi)}
$$
So you have the slope of the line now. Given that you know that line passes through $(-\pi,1/2)$, you can find the equation of the line.